# $addToSet in MongoDb with nested positional operators

Tags: arrays, mongodb, positional-operator

I want to add a value to an array that is inside another array. My document is like:

```
{categories:[{categoryName:"a category", items:[{itemName:"an item", arrayOfValues:[1]}]}]}
```

I would like to use $addToSet to arrayValues. To do so I am doing an update with a query

```
table.update({"categories.items.itemName" : "anItem"}, {$addToSet: "categories.$.items.$.arrayOfValues":"10"})
```

but I get an error: can't append to array using string field name [$]

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to update with nested arrays?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays inside arrays is considered bad mongodb design right now (mainly because you can't manipulate them efficiently, using `$addToSet` and friends). And you took it one step further and created arrays inside arrays inside arrays!

I understand that schema-less nature of MongoDB can cause a feeling that you can throw documents of **any** structure into it and handle them later. Unfortunately, this is not the reality. You have to know what you're doing, what features and limitations are there. In this case, you [can't use positional operator to push element to a nested array](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831).

Comment: @RemonvanVliet: did you not notice this link in my answer? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I notice that you said "manipulate them efficiently".  I encountered [this answer about `$push`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array), which also seems to work for `$addToSet`.  Is it just not efficient?  Do you have any thoughts about how inefficient it is?