# Push object in array with meteor 1.4?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm new in meteor and mongo I'd like to push one object in an array that is content in the other array. I'd like push giorni to cantieri. But I'd like push giorni in one specific cantieri. how can I make it? this my schema's collections.

```
`Clienti.Giorni = new SimpleSchema({
    giorno: {
        type: Date,
        label: "giorno del lavoro"
    },
    oraPartenza: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Giorno e ora partenza',
    },
    oraInizio: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Giorno e ora inizio',
        optional: true
    },
    oraFine: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Giorno e ora fine',
        optional: true
    },
    dipendenti: {
        type: [Dipendenti]
    }
});

Clienti.Cantieri = new SimpleSchema({
    _id:{
        type: String,
        autoValue: function(){
            var id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID();
            return id._str
        }
    },
    nome: {
        type: String
    },
    luogo: {
        type: String
    },
    inizio: {
        type: Date
    },
    scadenza: {
        type: Date
    },
    inCorso: {
        type: Boolean,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Creato il",
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date()
        }
    },
        giorni: {
        type: [Clienti.Giorni],
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    }
});

Clienti.ClienteSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    nome: {
        type: String,
        label: "nome"
    },
    iva: {
        type: String,
        label: "Partita iva",
        max: 16
    },
    referente: {
        type: String,
        label: "Nome persona di rifermento"
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        label: "email"
    },
    indirizzo:{
        type:String,
        label: 'Indirizzo'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Creato il",
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date()
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    },
    cantieri: {
        type: [Clienti.Cantieri],
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    }
});

Clienti.attachSchema( Clienti.ClienteSchema );`
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array)?

Comment: yes in effect I'm trying this solution 
`aggiungiGiorno: function(id,idC,doc,){
  Clienti.update({ _id: id, "cantieri._id": idC },{ $push: { 
   "cantieri.giorni": doc}
  });
 }
`
but the console log not return nothing and the document it'snt updated! I don't know how fix it?

Comment: [forum meteor](https://forums.meteor.com/t/push-object-in-array-help-me-please/29493/3)

Comment: You forgot the `$` in the field name.

Comment: where? how field name?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you are not getting errors when trying to update your `Clienti` collection. According to the [Simple Schema documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#schema-rules) in your schema definition, the `type` field should be a data type like `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Object` or a constructor function like `Date`, and you can use any of these inside of square brackets to define it as an array of those data types (e.g., `[String]`).

So, one issue is that in your `Clienti` collection, you have defined your data type for `cantieri` as `[Clienti.Cantieri]`. This is not an acceptable data type. If I am understanding what you are trying to do correctly, you probably want the `cantieri` field definition in your `Clienti` collection to look like:

```
cantieri: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        type: "hidden"
    }
}
```

And after this, you need to add each `cantieri` field under this item using the format:

```
cantieri.$.nome: {
    type: String
},
cantieri.$.luogo: {
    type: String
}
```

You also want to add the `giorni` fields under the `cantieri` fields in the `Clienti` collection in the same format:

```
giorni: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        type: "hidden"
    }
},
giorni.$.giorno: {
    type: Date,
    label: "giorno del lavoro"
},
giorni.$.oraPartenza: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Giorno e ora partenza',
}
```

Then, your method to update the database would look something like:

```
aggiungiGiorno: function(id, idC, doc,) { 
  Clienti.update({ 
    _id: id, 
    "cantieri._id": idC 
  }, { 
    $push: { 
      "cantieri": doc
    }
  });
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to combine your schemas as above, you should be able to also update the document using the query:

```
aggiungiGiorno: function(id, idC, doc,) { 
  Clienti.update({ 
    _id: id, 
    "cantieri._id": idC 
  }, { 
    $push: { 
      "cantieri.$.giorni": doc
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: [Combining SimpleSchemas](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#combining-simpleschemas) it's not the same thing?

Comment: Moreover new SimpleSchema is not an object?

Comment: I have updated my answer. To combine schemas, you should be able to keep your original code and use the query in my update.