# Insert array into sub-sub-document in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want to insert a value in the array of the sub document when the value is not already there.I have a collection like this

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ff25a74be508216afa9e03"),

    "RTODetails" : [
        {
            "pincode" : "34tgefgef",
            "state_name" : "Assam",
            "PUCDetails" : [
                {
                    "PUC_number" : "PUC755757",
                    "puc_year" : "2016"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
```

I want to add another array under PUCDetails like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ff25a74be508216afa9e03"),

    "RTODetails" : [
        {
            "pincode" : "34tgefgef",
            "state_name" : "Assam",
            "PUCDetails" : [
                {
                    "PUC_number" : "PUC755757",
                    "puc_year" : "2016"
                },
                {
                    "PUC_number" : "PUC755757111",
                    "puc_year" : "2017"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using

```
db.collection('vehicleDetails').update(
    { "_id": new ObjectId('57ff25a74be508216afa9e03') },
    {
        $push: {
            "RTODetails.$.PUCDetails":{
                "PUC_number" : "PUC755757111",
                "puc_year" : "2017"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

but it's not working.

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array

Comment: Already Tried the answer of the given link as specified in my question but it is not working in my case. I have already checked my _id.