# How to insert in nested Array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I see this in [Mongodb $push in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array)

What playlist.$.music represent.??

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": ID, "playlists._id": "58"},
    { "$push": 
        {"playlists.$.musics": 
            {
                "name": "test name",
                "duration": "4.00"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

---

my collection is like this .

```
"book" : [
        {
                "name" : "rupesh",
                "brand" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "classmate",
                                "price" : [
                                        {
                                                "RS" : 100,
                                                "Dollar" : 12
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
]
```

I want to add new price details like

```
price : [
       {
          "RS" : 100,
           "Dollar : 12
       },
        {
            "RS" : 150,
           "Dollar : 15
        } 
      ]
```

please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the **$** operator is used for updating, quoting from the MongoDB documentation on [`$` for update](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/),

> The positional **$** operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

So in the code above, `playlists.$.musics` part only states to update the property music of **first** document that matches the criteria on the first pipeline.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thnx for reply , but if  collection is like `book : [{ brand : [{ price : { doller : 7 ,euro : 20 } }] }] ` then if we want to add `price : {doller  : 8,euro : 22 } ` then ??

Comment: can I use `{$push : {"book.$.brand.$.price : {dollar : 8 , euro : 22 } } } `

Comment: Hi Rupesh, I don't think that will work. As what it says in the docu, 
_the **$** operator can not be used in queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays_.

Comment: ,so will you please provide me some suggestion for doing this?

Comment: Will the brand property have a unique identifier, or will only be an array type with field **price**?