# How can I insert a new entry inside Multilevel structure of mongoDB database?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on an app that contain details of an academic year in Multilevel structure of mongoDB database.

For this I've created structure like this:

```
[
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a1519a71fe8cc4df5888ff5"),
        "academicyear" : "2016-2017",
        "departments" : [
                {
                        "deptname" : "computer",
                        "semesters" : [
                                {
                                        "sem" : "2",
                                        "classes" : [
                                                {
                                                        "class" : "1",
                                                        "theory" : [
                                                                {
                                                                        "subname" : "DS",
                                                                        "faculty" : [
                                                                                {
                                                                                        "facultyname" : "KSS",
                                                                                        "facultydept" : "COMP"
                                                                                }
                                                                        ]
                                                                }
                                                        ],
                                                        "practical" : [
                                                                {
                                                                        "subname" : "DS",
                                                                        "batch" : [
                                                                                {
                                                                                        "bname" : "C",
                                                                                        "facultyname" : "KSS",
                                                                                        "facultydept" : "COMP"
                                                                                }
                                                                        ]
                                                                }
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}


]
```

Now for the same academic year and for the same department I would like to create a new semester node inside the array of semesters. For that I've tried syntax of $ and use of . operator but it did not worked well. How can I add a new semester node inside that semesters array? Also after creating a new semester node, how can I add a new class in an classes array?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

it could be done by means of the positional operator $[],

```
db.collection.update(
    { "academicyear": "2016-2017", "departments.deptname": "computer"},
    { "$push": 
        {"departments.$[].semesters": 
            {
                "sem" : "2",
                "classes" : [ ...
            }
        }
    }
)
```

It could also be done by indicating the position in the array if known. "departments.1.semesters", where 1 is the position of 'departments' in the array.

```
db.collection.update(
    { "academicyear": "2016-2017"},
    { "$push": 
        {"departments.1.semesters": 
            {
                "sem" : "2",
                "classes" : [ ...
            }
        }
    }
)
```

One way of doing it would be:

```
var toInsert = {"sem" : "2", "classes" : [ ... }
db.collection.update(
            { "academicyear": "2016-2017", departments: { $elemMatch: { deptname: "computer" } } },
            { $addToSet: { 'departments.$.semesters': toInsert } }
  )
```

The query part will find the document from the list array with id = 2. Then we use $ positional element to add a new element at that array index.

and the same would apply for classes.

```
db.collection.update(
    { "academicyear": "2016-2017"},
    { "$push": 
        {"departments.1.semesters.0.classes": 
            {
                "class" : "1",
                "theory" : [{ ...
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Another alternative would be to extract the document, update it on the returned object and save it again.

```
db.collection.findOne({"academicyear": "2016-2017", "departments.deptname": "computer"}, {'departments.semesters': 1}, (err, doc) => {
        if(err) return handleError(res)(err); 
        if(!doc) return res.send(404).end();

        //I guess semester is 0, but you can find the one that you are going to update by some filter
        doc.departments[0].semesters[0].classes.push({...});

          doc.save( (err) => {
            if(err) return handleError(res)(err)

            return res.status(200).end();
          });  

      });
```