# Push and remove two dimensional array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have following document sample:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a569c3d093322018b514e31"),
"participants" : [
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("5a446a6169c8343283bdb1ad"),
        "unreadMessages" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("5a4ff9bded4bae532bdd35f9"),
        "unreadMessages" : [ ]
    }
],
"created" : ISODate("2018-01-11T01:08:39.736Z")
```

I am given _id(5a569c3d093322018b514e31) and user id(5a446a6169c8343283bdb1ad).

How I can push a text string (test test) into the unreadMessages array of the first element in participants?

Comment: Try `db.collection.update(
   { _id:ObjectId("5a569c3d093322018b514e31"), "participants.user":ObjectId("5a446a6169c8343283bdb1ad")  },
   { "$push": { "participants.$.unreadMessages" : "test test"} }
)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb $push in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array)