# How to update an array of objects without using loop or scan database

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Here I want to update 1 field for **all elements in an array of objects**. How to update that field with only one query without looping and updating each of the elements or scanning the whole database and matching?

My model schema:

```
let NameCardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    occupation: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    company: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
    },
    position: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
    },
    userID: [String] // field to update
});
```

Sample data:

```
User:
    _id:5b8e4c6a879ac54ee0f30bb3
    username:"Duc"

Namecard array:
[
    namecard1:
        _id:5b9615c6b157af5afc8ce426
        occupation:null
        company:"KIS"
        position:"Developer"
        fullname:"Duc Nguyen Trung"
        userID:"5b9a173f0749c52b583818ec"

    namecard2:
        _id:5b96162fb157af5afc8ce428
        occupation:null
        company:"KIS"
        position:"Developer"
        fullname:"Hieu Vuong"
        userID:"5b9a16700749c52b583818ea"
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    namecard1:
        _id:5b9615c6b157af5afc8ce426
        occupation:null
        company:"KIS"
        position:"Developer"
        fullname:"Duc Nguyen Trung"
        userID:"5b9a173f0749c52b583818ec", "5b8e4c6a879ac54ee0f30bb3" // username Duc's ID added

    namecard2:
        _id:5b96162fb157af5afc8ce428
        occupation:null
        company:"KIS"
        position:"Developer"
        fullname:"Hieu Vuong"
        userID:"5b9a16700749c52b583818ea", "5b8e4c6a879ac54ee0f30bb3" // username Duc's ID added
]
```

Comment: Could you please share some sample data and tell us which field you actually want to change in what way? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @dnickless I want to append new `userID` data to the `userID` field. All I can think of is just loop and scan mentioned above

Comment: If you post some sample data (input data and desired result) I'm pretty sure we can find a solution for you.

Comment: @dnickless I've added sample data as you said

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a new entry into the `userID` array of all documents just execute this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({ /* no filter */ }, { $push: { "Namecards.$[].userID": "5b8e4c6a879ac54ee0f30bb3" } })
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I want to update the documents belong to the elements of the object array only, not all documents of the collection

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean. Can you please post the exact JSON shape of the involved documents?

Comment: I mean I have an array of `NameCard` object with 2 elements as the sample above, and I just want to update their `userID` field of those elements only. And I want to do it with some kind of query, not looping the whole array or scanning the whole database to match their `_id`. I wonder if there are any kinds of query for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I originally thought you had individual documents per Namecard

Comment: Posibly duplicated post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array

Comment: @vitomadio: this question is slightly different because he wants to update all elements in the array but, true, that, too, has been asked her lots of times. ;)