# Mongoos -> Model.update() -> SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 80

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 80
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

```
const User = require('../models/user')
const App = require('../models/app')

exports.add_app_to_collection = (req, res) => {
  let application = {}
  App.find({_id: req.body.appId}, (err, app) => {
    application = app

  })

  User.update({
    "_id": req.body.userID, 
    "collections.collName": req.body.collID
  }, 
  {
    $push: {"collections.$.collApps": application
  }})
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "the app is added to collection"
    })
  })
}
```

Both `User` and `App` are mongoose models. I expect the problem is inside the first parameter of the update function but I do not know how to solve it. I tried to not to use double quotes for `_id` and `collections.collName` but it still does not work.

**Note:** I used this answer if you want to know what I am doing. [Mongodb $push in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875706/7565577)

Comment: Try printing the JSON first before feeding it to your update function. See if it is a valid JSON. There may be some unwanted characters. You can use any online JSON Pretty tool to check easily.

Comment: Where's the actual JSON?

Comment: Q: do I am allowed to use JSON object inside the `update`? I used update function  before but only with js objects, not with a JSON object.

Comment: All the examples of update function I saw use JS objects not JSON!!

Comment: If you add a breakpoint on this update code and go to the point where you see the JSON: Unexpected string error, you'll find the actual problem. I'm not sure for this particular use case but JSON should do good at most of the places where simple JS Object is expected. However JSON should be valid!

Comment: Please mention the code at position 80 at which error is occurred