# Mongoose - How to push object in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-update

I have this data structure in my MongoDB database:

```
"menu": [
        {
            "dishCategory":"61e6089f209b802518e2b4a4",
            "dishMeals": [
                {
                    "dishMealName": "Burger King",
                    "dishMealIngredients": "Burger lepinja, bbq sos, berlin sos, zelena"
                    "dishMealPrice": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

How do I push a new object inside **dishMeals** in exact **dishCategory** ( I am providing `dishCategoryId`, `newDish` object and _id of restaurant through req.body) I've tried this but nothing is changing:

```js
await Restaurants.updateOne(
        {
            '_id' : _id,
            'menu.dishCategory' : dishCategoryId
        },
        {
            $push : {
                'menu.$.dishMeals' : newDish
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use [`arrayFilters`](https://database.guide/how-the-arrayfilters-parameter-works-in-mongodb/) to filter the nested document(s) in the array field, then `$push` if the filter criteria in the `arrayFilters` met.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": _id,
  "menu.dishCategory": dishCategoryId
},
{
  $push: {
    "menu.$[menu].dishMeals": newDish
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "menu.dishCategory": dishCategoryId
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GMdbyyhtvdz)

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake I have  "dishCategory":"61e6089f209b802518e2b4a4" not the object one like earlier. When I try like this "menu.dishCategory": dishCategoryId" Its not working

Comment: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GMdbyyhtvdz) looks fine for me. Maybe another thing to look up is make sure you pass the value with exact type, for example, if `dishCategory` is ObjectId, then the value of `dishCategoryId` must also be ObjectId type as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `arrayFilters` config in `update` query:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "restaurant_id": 1
},
{
  "$push": {
    "menu.$[element].dishMeals": {
      "dishMealName": "Best Burger",
      "dishMealIngredients": "Best burger in town",
      "dishMealPrice": 10
    }
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "element.dishCategory._id": "61e6089f209b802518e2b4a4"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iV8sg-YCtSZ)

Comment: Thank you your method is working fine it was my mistake for not checking if dishCategory is indeed an ObjectId not a string

Answer (score 2):

You may read the question and the solution they provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875706), Hope this one will be helpful to you.

```
db.collection.update({
    "_id": 1,
    "menu.dishCategory": "61e6089f209b802518e2b4a4"
},
{
    $push: {
        "menu.$.dishMeals": newMeal
    }
})
```

[Sample Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JxOna_5Q1MT)

Comment: Thank you your method is working fine it was my mistake for not checking if dishCategory is indeed an ObjectId not a string