# Mongoose pushing values to a specific key of an array of objects

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    images: {
      type: [{id: String, url: String, description: String, likes: []}],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I want to push the user id to the likes array of a specific image object in the array (identified by the postid). The query below successfully identifies the correct document but doesn't update it:

```
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {'images.id': postid},
      {$push: {likes:
              {userid}}},
)
```

I have also tried

```
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {'images.id': postid},
      {$push: {'images.likes':
              {userid}}},
)
```

But neither of these approaches work.

Comment: `{ $push : { likes : userid } }`?

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: what does kind of work is: {
          $push: {
            'images.$[].likes':
            userid
          }
        } But this pushes to all the likes arrays of the images, as opposed to just the image with a specific id.

Comment: Found the answer here for anyone else looking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70779241/mongoose-how-to-push-object-in-nested-array-of-objects