# How to update nested arrays in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have an update function that creates a new array of campaigns inside a MongoDB document. Each campaign inside “campaigns” array has a “name” and another array called “leads”

This is how I’m creating it:

```
await users.updateMany(
  { email: user.email },
  { $push: { campaigns: { name: campaignname, type, leads: [] } } }
);
```

Now what I want to do is “add” some data(array of objects) to the “leads” array with a specified campaign name.

So I essentially want to search for user, select the campaign inside the campaigns array by the “name” field and push the array of objects inside the “leads” array.

I tried:

```
await users.updateOne({
  $push: {
    "campaigns.$[elem].leads": { $each: leads }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.name": campaignname
    }
  ]
})
```

Doesn't work

Please anyone help promptly

Comment: Comment if you want further clarification

Comment: Are you using mongoose or native mongodb driver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb $push in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```js
const doc = await users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        email: user.email,
        campaigns: {
            $elemMatch:{
                name: campaignname
            }
        }
    },
    {
       $push: {
          "campaigns.$.leads": {
             $each: [
                {key: 'value'},
                {key: 'value'}
             ]
          }
       }
}, {new: true}); //< {new: true} is mongoose specific
```

or if your array of objects to push is already constructed you can use spread syntax :

```js
const arr = [{key: 'value'}, {key: 'value'}]
const doc = await users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        email: user.email,
        campaigns: {
            $elemMatch:{
                name: campaignname
            }
        }
    },
    {
       $push: {
          "campaigns.$.leads": {
             $each: [
                ...arr
             ]
          }
       }
}, {new: true}); //< {new: true} is mongoose specific
```

To remove one of these objects from the `campaigns.leads` array then you can select them by their `{key: 'value'}` with a `$pull` like so:

```js
const doc = await users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        email: user.email,
        campaigns: {
            $elemMatch:{
                name: campaignname
            }
        }
    },
    {
       $pull: {
          "campaigns.$.leads": {
             key: 'value'
          }
       }
}, {new: true});
```

or if you just want to remove them all you can set the `campaigns.leads` to an empty array like so:

```js
const doc = await users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        email: user.email,
        campaigns: {
            $elemMatch:{
                name: campaignname
            }
        }
    },
    {
       $set: {
          "campaigns.$.leads": []
       }
}, {new: true});
```

Comment: You're welcome, the trick is to use `$elemMatch` in the query then you can use the `$` positional operator in the update which singles out array element from the previous match. `$each` is necessary for pushing multiple objects but I think you already gathered that from your example. @Saswat

Comment: Any chance you can show me how I can delete each obj inside the campaigns.$.leads?

Comment: @Saswat I've added a couple of examples.

Comment: what I meant was remove a specific lead inside campaign > campaign > leads. Let's say each lead is an object like this {leadName: 'xyz',details: 'test'}

Comment: any ideas on that? @jQueeny

Comment: Yes inside the `$pull` just replace my `key: 'value'` with `leadName: 'xyz',details: 'test'`.

Comment: my bad I didn't see the second last example. Really appreciate you taking out time to help me man. I mean just helping a total stranger get off problems without asking for anything is truly generous. Keep doing the good work man

Comment: @Saswat you're welcome. Hopefully you do the same and help someone else with their code.