# how to make it unique mongoose object schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model with category links like down below

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// USER SCHEMA MODEL FOR MONGODB //

const categoryLinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  label: String,
  link: String,
  links: { type: Array, default: [] }
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
  password: String,
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
  categoryLinks: [categoryLinkSchema],
  links : { type : Array , "default" : [] },
  imagelink: String,
  plan: String,
  bakiye: Number,
  phoneNumber: Number
});
```

I can update a user by using the code below

```
  try{
     const newCat = {
        label: "bim-bebek",
        link: "https://bim.bebek",
        links: ["12", "25"]
     }

     const user = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate({
           email: "asdf@gmail.com"
        },
        {
           $push: {
              categoryLinks: newCat
           }
        },
        { new: true }
     );
     console.log("updated");
  }catch(err){
     console.log(err);
  }
```

This way I update the user's specific `categoryLinks` yet if i add 2 categories with the same `label` for example `labelA` they get added, yet I want the `label` to be unique for each user...

So if I do

```
const categoryLinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  label: {type: String, unique: true},
  link: String,
  links: { type: Array, default: [] }
});
```

Instead, I see it doesn't work... I can still see duplicate categoryLinks =>

```
"categoryLinks":[{"label":"bim-bebek","link":"https://bim.bebek","links":["12","25"],"_id":{"$oid":"65a8077212468e2f8bca482f"}},{"label":"bim-bebek","link":"https://bim.bebek","links":["12","25"],"_id":{"$oid":"65a80781bfc86357bc798091"}}]
```

How can I make an object's unique of a subdocument in mongoose?

Update: `"label":"bim-bebek"` can exist in multiple user document. The labels are only unique for the current user document.

Comment: Can `"label":"bim-bebek"` exist in another User document? I know you want it unique per `categoryLinks` array but can two Users have a `categoryLinks` object with `"label":"bim-bebek"`?

Comment: yes ```"label":"bim-bebek"``` can exist in other user document. The labels are only unique for the current user.  @jQueeny

Comment: possibly any way to achieve this task ? @jQueeny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom validator function to the `categoryLinks` array within the `userSchema` not the `categoryLinkSchema`.

This is best because it will ensure that duplicates don't get added when you first create a document. This is soemthing that is often overlooked.

However, because of how the validator works you will need to handle updates slightly differently so that each `categoryLinks` object is validated against the whole array and not just against the update document.

Update your `categoryLinkSchema` as follows to include the `validate` property. Take note of the changes to the way the `categoryLinks` property is written too.

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  //...
  //...
  categoryLinks: {
    type: [categoryLinkSchema],
    validate: [function(doc) {
        for(let d of doc){
            const duplicates = this.categoryLinks.filter(function(c){
                return c.label === d.label;
            })
            if(duplicates.length > 1){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }, 'Each categoryLinks.label must be unique.']
  },
  //...
});
```

This validator is taking the `categoryLinks` array and for each object within the array it is comparing the `label` value against every other `label` value that exists in the whole `categoryLinks` array. If there are more than two it will `return false`.

Now when you do an update you can use `push()` and `save()` which will run the validator automatically. Here is an example:

```js
const newCat = {
   label: "bim-bebek",
   link: "https://bim.bebek",
   links: ["12", "25"]
}
const user = await userModel.findOne({email: "asdf@gmail.com"});
if(user){
   user.categoryLinks.push(newCat);
   await user.save();
}
```

Comment: When I register a new user I get the error ```MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.usermodels index: categoryLinks.label_1 dup key: { categoryLinks.label: null }
```
so maybe i should also add ```!== null```

like this?
```return (c.link === d.link || c.label === d.label) & d.label !== null;```

Comment: It looks like you have created an index on `categoryLinks.label` previously. This validation function work instead of an index. If you connect to mongodb with compass and select your collection you can click the indexes tab to check. Just drop the index. Also, you need to find out why you are adding null values, unless that is your intention of course. @unbaym

Comment: yes i created a new **user**, so the ```categoryLinks``` in the document seems to be just an empty array. and then when i try to create anotjher new one i get this error,  tried with ```!==null``` seemed to not work.. then need to make a check to make sure it is not filtering a new instance..

Comment: myCurrentValidation looks like this, ```for(let d of doc){
            const duplicates = this.categoryLinks.filter(function(c){
                return (c.link === d.link || c.label === d.label) & d.label !== null;
            })
            if(duplicates.length > 1){
                return false;
            }
        }```

Comment: the funny thing is, it only happens after i create 1 user which then has an empty instance of label... so it means it is checking other user's ```categoryLinks.label``` as well, instead of making it unique for the current user ? maybe my current validation above is wrong ?

Comment: The `MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error` only happens when you have an active index. The validate function you're using is separate from an index. I would recommend you drop the index because it's checking for unique `categoryLinks.label` per document. From what I gather 2 users can have the same `categoryLinks.label` value but a single user must have unique `categoryLinks.label`. An index is working against you. Just [drop the index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/).

Comment: yes done and deleted the index alongside ```username``` and ```emaail``` i don't know how ```categoryLinks.label``` got added as an index, or how does by default mongo chose it is interesting. 

@jQueeny thank you for all support through, can you please take a look at my latest questions when you have time ? Much Love!

Comment: I think having an index on `username` and `email` would be quite useful so that you don't get duplicates on those fields. Adding those two indexes back in would be wise @unbaym

Comment: any way we talk to each other through email ? you know my email ends with @sabanciuniv.edu I have a question with mongodb database design,

Comment: @unbaym unfortunately I'm not in a position to email you directly. If you have a MongoDB design issue you can post a question. There are lots of good developers on SO that can help.

Comment: ok understood, an element inside links array inside ```categoryLinks``` look like this: ```{"url": url, "price": Number}```
if i want to update the price of a specfic element in the array, do i have to use something like to ```findOneAndUpdate``` ? also for updating just 1 element in that ```categoryLinks.links``` which operation is the most efficient (for performace and speed). 
As a note: I might need to also update multiple user's ```categoryLinks.links``` specific element, if they all follow the same ```categoryLinks.link```

Comment: or something like ```push``` again ? thank you for your time, i am banned from asking new question, so i had to post here specifically to you... thank you for time

Comment: @unbaym there are few ways to update array elements. You can `$pull` a matching element from the array, you can `$push` a new element to the array or you can `$set` an existing value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77747401/21972629) for possible example.

Comment: very very lasty, maybe possibly even i can edit this question by adding 1 more question ( icant ask questions i am banned) 

how to delete a categryLinks by ```label``` for example ? i want to delete a categoryLink and find it by ```label```

much love...

Comment: You can do `const doc = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate({"categoryLinks.label": "bim-bebek"},  {  $pull: { categoryLinks : {"label": "bim-bebek"}  } }, { new : true });`  or if you want to match a specific user then it's `const doc = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId},  {  $pull: { categoryLinks : {"label": "bim-bebek"}  } }, { new : true });` Why are you banned?